# Cant get views_exposed_form to submit correctly

Tags: taxonomy-terms, views

I needed to have all taxonomy vocabularies available to filter on, without adding all of the taxonomies one at a time.

I did this using the Content: Has taxonomy terms (Multiple) Filter - which renders out as a multiple select list.

I needed to change the select list to checkboxes, but BEF didnt allow me to do that for this type of field, so i did the following...

```
function MYMODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {

  if ($form_id == 'views_exposed_form') {

      $options = $form['filter']['#options'];
      unset($form['filter']);

      foreach($options as $vocab => $terms) {

        foreach ($terms as $key => $value) {
            $newkey = $options[$vocab][$key]->option;
            $termoptions[$vocab][key($newkey)] = $newkey[key($newkey)];
        }
        $form[$vocab] = array(
          '#type' => 'checkboxes',
          '#options' => $termoptions[$vocab],
          '#title' => $vocab,
          '#multiple' => TRUE,

        );

      }

  }

}
```

The exposed form looks good, but it doesnt work.

I think its because the name of the query is wrong. As i have split up the heirarchy into separate fields, the url used to look like

> mysite.com/category?filter[]=123

Now it looks like...

> mysite.com/category?Brand[123]=123

So theres how far ive got, any ideas how i can make this exposed form work?

I had a poke around at changing the submit handler views_exposed_form_submit but i dont know what i would need to change.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at https://www.drupal.org/node/2882381 and let me know if the patch in comment #6 meets your needs.

If so, please test that patch and report back the results of your tests in that issue.

Thanks!